# ReadFile function for an anonymous pipe

Tags: c++, windows, ipc

I have a question about Windows pipes. In `ReadFile` function manual is written:

> If an anonymous pipe is being used and the write handle has been closed, when ReadFile attempts to read using the pipe's corresponding read handle, the function returns FALSE and GetLastError returns ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE.

Lets assume that read from a pipe occurs every second. From the last read operation the following has happened: the write to the pipe operation and a close of the write handler. According to the manual above, the function returns false - reading operation fail. My question what happens with data that was not read? How I can get them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you'd probably expect, after data has been put into the pipe, you can read it out until you reach the end of the data, *then* reading will fail.

Comment: So, when the `ReadFile` returns `false` with `ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE` error. It does not mean that the function fail, it means that it did its job (read the last data from the pipe)?

Comment: @user14416: Yes -- if you (for example) spawn a child that writes some output then exits, it's expected that you'll read the data then get ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE. Of course, it *could* also mean the child crashed, or something on that order.

Comment: I believe that the call to ReadFile that gets the last data from the pipe will succeed, and the next call will return ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE.  In other words the error is postponed until the pipe is empty.